# Combine two separate Find and Format Macros into one

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, format, find

At the moment, I'm using two separate Macros to find a specific text in Word document and execute certain formatting commands (different for each search). For convenience, I want to somehow combine the two into one.

This is the first one:

```
With Selection.Find
.Text = "potatoes"
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.MatchWildcards = True
End With
'
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
Repeat (3)
```

And the second one:

```
With Selection.Find
.Text = "tomatoes"
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.MatchWildcards = True
End With
'
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
Repeat (2)
```

In my case, only one of the searches will be true and will return a result.

So the idea is something like this ...

- If you find "potatoes" do the first case formatting and don't search for "tomatoes".
- If you find "tomatoes" do the second case formatting and don't search for "potatoes".

  - Or ... If you don't find "potatoes", search for "tomatoes" and do the second case formatting.

Comment: So you are asking how to create an `If` statement?

Comment: Yes, I can create simple ones, but this is way out of my capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Dim fnd As Boolean
fnd = False
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="potatoes", Forward:=True, _
        MatchWildcards:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop, MatchCase:=True) = True
        fnd = True
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
        Selection.InsertAfter vbCr
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End With
If fnd = False Then
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        Do While .Execute(FindText:="tomatoes", Forward:=True, _
        MatchWildcards:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop, MatchCase:=True) = True
            Selection.InsertAfter vbCr
            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Also I want to repeat `Selection.InsertParagraphAfter` or in your example `Selection.InsertAfter vbCr` certain amount of times.

Comment: Replace

Selection.InsertAfter vbCr

with

Selection.InsertAfter vbCr & vbCr

adding as many & vbCr as required